# deleting all the file of certain size

Tags: python, perl, shell

i have bunch of log files and I have to delete the files of some small sizes, which were erroneous files that got created. ( 63bytes ).
I have to copy only those files which have data in it .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Shell (linux);

```
find . -type f -size 63c -delete
```

Will traverse subdirectories (unless you tell it otherwise)

Comment: ~unutbu's addition of a directory is possible, but not needed (defaults to working dir) although it would be nice to illustrate multiple paths can be given: `find ./foo/bar ./foz ../../baz -type f` would search all 3 directories at once.

Comment: @Wrikken: Not all versions of `find` default to the current directory. It's best to explicitly specify the directory to avoid unexpectedly failing commands later.

Comment: Ah? Which version /  platform doesn't might I ask? Not that there is anything wrong with being explicit, especially when deleting, just curious.

Comment: @Wrikken: GNU find is the only one I know of that defaults to "."; BSD-derived versions tend to require the path argument. I happen to have an OSF/1 machine handy that also requires a path argument.

Answer (score 10):

Since you tagged your question with "python" here is how you could do this in that language:

```
target_size = 63
import os
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files: 
        path = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
        if os.stat(path).st_size == target_size:
            os.remove(path)
```

Answer (score 6):

The Perl one liner is

```
perl -e 'unlink grep {-s == 63} glob "*"'
```

Although, it is always a good idea to test what it would do before running it:

```
perl -le 'print for grep {-s == 63} glob "*"'
```

If you want to walk an entire directory tree, you will need a different versions:

```
#find all files in the current hierarchy that are 63 bytes long.
perl -MFile::Find=find -le 'find sub {print $File::Find::name if -s == 63}, "."'

#delete all files in the current hierarchy that 63 bytes long
perl -MFile::Find=find -e 'find sub {unlink if -s == 63}, "."'
```

I am using need [`$File::Find::name`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html#%24File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aname-is-the-complete-pathname-to-the-file.) in the finding version so you get the whole path, the unlinking version doesn't need it because [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) changes directory into the each target directory and sets [`$_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24_) to be the file name (which is how [`-s`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) and [`unlink`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html) get the filename).  You may also want to look up [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) and [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)